hashrate vs hashpower, which tag is better?
We currently have both 

hashrate
The hash rate is the measuring unit of the processing power of the Bitcoin network. 
hashpower
(no description)

Additionally we have

hash
(no description)
hashing
A hash is a mathematically reproducible but irreversible process which takes one value as an input and predictably produces a derived value as an output. Hashing is central to Bitcoin mining as well as the generation of Bitcoin addresses.


Not only is the hashrate not "processing power" because more doesn't increase the amount of transaction processing that is done, but at least the first two seem to be duplicates of one another.
Which one should we keep?

We should merge hashing into hash, because the latter looks nicer, and merge hashrate into hashpower, because the latter is more popular.
We should also fix the description on hashrate
Edit: Done.
